# Android views are null after rotation when using Rx-Java

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2, kotlin-android-extensions

I'm accessing all of the views in a fragment with Kotlin Android Extensions, this views work as expected and can be accessed normally even after screen rotations.

The problem starts when i try to access the views inside an Rx-Java observable interval like this:

```
 var interval = Observable.interval(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS, Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())

interval.retry().subscribe { updateUi(); }
```

If i rotate the screen between intervals. The next time the updateUi() method is run as a part of the observable, the views inside it will be null and the application will crash with the following exception:

> io.reactivex.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: text_view must not be null

But if i try to run the method outside the observable, everything will work correctly.

I know that accessing the views with findViewById() will retrieve the view correctly, but that defeats the purpuose of having the kotlin-android-extensions.

Comment: View hierarchy is valid between onCreateView and onDestroyView. Typically you (un)register observers i.e. (un)subscribe observables in onStart and onStop. Leave your timer running in a ViewModel and subscribe your UI to it only when actually needed, that's in onStart and dispose in onStop. That way you won't leak old view hierarchy.

Comment: I'm already using ViewModel. The call to the updateUi() method actually triggers an update as well as update some ui components(the part that crashes) I'm a bit confused on what you mean by putting the timer inside the viewmodel. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On rotation, the screen is being set up again, so the old views are gone.

You have to unsubscribe the subscription (returned by `subscribe()` call) in the `onStop()`.

Maybe you should try out `ViewModel` of the Android architectures. I've been using it lately and really liking it. This will take care of your issue too. https://medium.com/google-developers/viewmodels-a-simple-example-ed5ac416317e

Comment: I'm already using ViewModel. Inside the updateUi() methods there is a call to update the ViewModel as well as update some ui components (the part that crashes). The Observable interval is to have something like an auto-refresh feature in the app.

Comment: Ok, then it still looks like you should handle the behaviour in the ViewModel and unsubscribe in the onCleared() of the ViewModel